# Terraform Error: Failed to load plugin schemas

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm adding a new module to an existing project.
I get the message that I have to do a terraform init to recognise the new module.

aws.tf:

```
provider "aws" { 
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_key
  region     = var.region
}
```

terraform.tfvars:

```
access_key = "Removed"
secret_key = "Removed"
region     = "ap-southeast-2"
```

When I do that, it downloads the latest aws

```
- Installing hashicorp/aws v4.40.0...
```

Then I get below...

> │ Error: Failed to load plugin schemas
> │
> │ Error while loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for
> │ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws: failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" to
> │ obtain schema: Unrecognized remote plugin message:
> │
> │ This usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply
> │ needs to be recompiled to support the latest protocol...
> ╵

So seems the latest aws schema is corrupt???
I can't progress.
I've copied over an older aws schema but I still have to do a terraform init and it always updates the aws schema. So stuck here.

Even if i create a new folder and have nothing in the folder and just start with terraform on its own and do an init, it creates the .terraform folder and installs the aws schema.
Then do terraform plan I get the schema error.

Terraform v1.3.5
AWS schema v4.40.0
Windows 10
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the TF code producing the error?

Comment: Do you have the `terraform` block in your code with `required_providers`?

Comment: Marcin - The code is as above.

Comment: Marko,- I didn't have required_providers so copied straight from hashicorp examples for AWS. Still same error.

Comment: OK the problem was the Trend Micro Anti Virus killing the process. I've whitelisted terraform.exe in the client computer and all good now. Thanks for the responses. Hopefully this helps someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem was the Trend Micro Anti Virus killing the process. I've whitelisted terraform.exe in the client computer and all good now. Thanks for the responses. Hopefully this helps someone in future.